# Trying to get a "Is between" date filter to work... it is returning an offset by + 1 days.

Tags: 7, datetime, views

Please see my website to see what i'm talking about: http://apollo.tbc.iit.edu/~spaceweather/sw_test/?q=download-cases-data#

Ive found some examples and posts on how to do this but even after following them i'm still having issues.

I'm trying to filter the results shown in a table. I want the dates in between the two specified dates a user might put in.

When I select 05/24/2013-05/26/2013 I get an offset of 05/25/2013-05/27/2013 for the results. Can anyone help with this?  I'm storing the date as a Unix time stamp.

Thank you for your help!

(*Note my website has been updated according to the suggestion below by @adem .)

[image: Website snippet]

Comment: It might be helpful if someone can help me understand how i can begin to go through the code for the date/time module or views filters to understand where this issue is arising.  I suspect there is a difference between the filter and how it actually uses a Unix time stamp (epoch) but I have a hard time getting started debugging this.

Comment: The dates are stored in the database table as epochs and are converted using DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-z',...) in a php script i use to first insert the data into the database.   Then I use the data module to pull that data into drupal.  I can then access this table from the views interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my own issue, which as with most quirky issues like this end up being buried in the details that other users wont know right away.

When I put these dates into my database I used an offset timezone for "America/Chicago".  In the on the Drupal side it was displaying the time in UTC which happens to be forward 5 hours from CST time.

I went to edit the field I created for these dates and changed the timezone from UTC to "America/Chicago" and it fixed the issue. Everything filters nicely now.

Here is a screen shot of where i found this option to change things.   I hope this helps others who might see an unexpected offset in their days.    Always make sure your timezones are correct to what youre expecting!

[image: Look at the Time zone Option!!!]

Answer (score 1):

The filter type must be "single filter", 
operator must be "is between", as demonstrated in this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I made this change. It is nice they have this option like this.  Much easier than doing the two filters.  Anyway it still has the strange offset issue.  When i'm selecting 5/24-5/26 it gives me 5/25-5/27.  Is this some kind of issue with time zones or something weird? Please [click here](http://apollo.tbc.iit.edu/~spaceweather/sw_test/?q=download-cases-data&fileDate[min][date]=Friday%2C%20May%2024%2C%202013&fileDate[max][date]=Sunday%2C%20May%2026%2C%202013&fileRec=All&items_per_page=100&&order=fileDate&sort=asc) to see the change